# Using @LoadBalanced in RestTemplate is not load balancing restTemplate in Brixton Release

Tags: spring-cloud, microservices, resttemplate

We have **migrated our spring cloud from 1.0 version to Brixton Release**. As per the github documentation we now have to explicitly mark **@LoadBalanced** for the **RestTemplate** object. But , we are observing that Rest Template is not able to pick the load balanced list of server by ribbon.. After investigating we found that **LoadBalancerInterceptor which should be included in RestTemplate object is not there in RestTemplate object.**
  In earlier cloud release , LoadBalancerInterceptor was already included with RestTemplate and we did not have to declare it manually. What is the way forward can anybody pls share ..

Comment: Found the solution , we had to explicitly add the ClientHttpRequestFactory  by autowiring and set it to RestTemplate object and our api was sucessfully discovered using netflix discoveryclient(which was also autowired) as our DiscoveryServer was running in 1.0.x spring cloud NOT in Brixton rel. Hope this solution may help somebody

Comment: joy-chowdhury could please provide the example ?